# How to merge two onActivityResult?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

im doing online application. One of the functions are user can choose photo from their gallery or take photo from their camera.Now i have trouble in onActivityResult method where i failed to merge it.Hope anyone can help me to merge it so that the images that user choose or took can view in my ImageView (image_view). This is my main activity:

```
**private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private Button button_1;
public int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
private ImageView image_view;
private Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sell);

    image_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resul);
    button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
        }
    });

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        try {
            // We need to recyle unused bitmaps
            if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();
            image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult2(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri targetUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
            image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

enter code here

Answer (score 1):

You do not need create two `onActivityResult()` method for two `startActivityForResult` call. Just provide different request code in both `startActivityForResult` call. and `onActivityResult` will notify you with given request code to identify the result.

```
private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 100;
private static final int CHOOSE_PICTURE = 101;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sell);

    image_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resul);
    button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            // Here provide TAKE_PICTURE request code to identify the IMAGE_CAPTURE result in onActivityResult method. 
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
        }
    });

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            // Here provide CHOOSE_PICTURE request code to identify the ACTION_PICK result in onActivityResult method.     android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_PICTURE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            // Do something with take picker result
    }else if (requestCode == CHOOSE_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            // Do something with choose image result
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer [Starting Activities and Getting Results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) for more information.